# How Can I Develop Windows Phone Application Through (Windows7(32bit))

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I need to know if I can develop windows phone applications through the vs2012 with my computer

**my computer has :**

1- windows 7 OS .

2- 32 bit .

3- VS2012 .

I heard that you cannot develop windows phone 8 application through windows 7?

Can I use windows phone 7?

How can I download it ?

Comment: The System Requirements section on the [Phone 8 SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35471) download page leaves very little to the imagination.  Even if you somehow know to fool the installer, there is still no scenario where you can debug and test your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows Phone 8 development is possible on a Windows 7 OS using Visual Studio 2012. The Windows Phone 8 emulator, however, requires Window 8 64bit to run.

[System requirements for Windows Phone Emulator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff626524%28v=vs.105%29.aspx):

> The Windows Phone SDK 8.0 setup program checks the prerequisites for running Windows Phone 8 Emulator. It displays warnings if the prerequisites are not present, but it does not require them.
>
> If your computer or your network doesn't support all the requirements for running the emulator, you can still install the SDK and develop apps for Windows Phone 8. **You can only debug and test them, however, on a registered Windows Phone 8 phone.**

In short, the requirements for writing Windows Phone 8 applications on Windows 7 are:

- Visual Studio 2012
- Windows Phone 8 SDK
- Registered Windows Phone 8 device
- [Windows Phone Developer Account](http://dev.windowsphone.com/en-us/join)

Comment: Thanks you so much ,,
do you mean i can develop Windows phone Application using 32bit ?
if it yes .
from where i can download the SDK ?

Comment: @llnspectable Can You Review My Comment Please

Comment: @lo2i Unfortunately, the SDK tools require a 64-bit OS, so developing Windows Phone 8 applications on Windows 7 32-bit is not possible. Not even when using a virtual machine - this also requires a 64-bit host OS. Getting the SDK installed on Windows 7 64-bit isn't trivial either: [Tutorial: Install Windows Phone 8 SDK on Windows 7 the Easy Way](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2422751)

Comment: @llnspectable I will try to instal windows phone 7 sdk , i think it works with 32 bit

Comment: @lo2i The tools are **required** to build application installer packages. Those tools do not run on a 32-bit version of Windows. In other words: Windows 7 32-bit cannot be used to build an .xap to upload to a device.

Comment: @llnspectable

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=27570

in Windows phone 7 the requirements is 

- Windows 7, Windows Vista - Windows 7 (x86 and x64)
 And i install the SDK And it works fine now with the Emulator :)

Comment: @lo2i Windows Phone 7 has lower requirements. However, I was under the impression that you explicitly asked for Windows Phone 8. The latter requires a 64-bit OS.

Comment: @llnspectable sorry for that ,, and thank you very much for everything :)